# R approxfun() returns "error in xy.coords: object 'y' not found"

Tags: r, function

I tried to follow the second example from `?approxfun`, but I have an error right from the start and can't seem to find anything related to this...

When I run `f <- approxfun(x,y)`, it gives me the following error:

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, setLab = FALSE) : object 'y' not found
```

I'm not even telling `approxfun` to do anything as I'm simply trying to define the function `f`, so why is this happening?

I've restarted Rstudio and the problem still persists. I'm running R version 4.0.2 on Windows 10, and currently have the following base packages attached (from `sessionInfo()`): `stats` `graphics` `grDevice utils` `datasets` `methods` `base` Is it possible any of these packages are somehow messing up `approxfun`?

Comment: The definition of the function depends on both x and y.  This does not make sense unless both x and y are defined.  It looks like your y is not defined.

Comment: The example in the help file defines `y` as `rnorm(10)`.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Oh god, I don't know why I thought those two blocks were separate examples. You're totally right, sorry for the dumb question!!